# Launch file for turtlebot dashboard?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Related to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/3618/multiple-robots-under-one-core?answer=5651#5651) post that talks about multiple robots under one core. Oviously I want to be able to see the dashboards for each robot, so I created this launchfile:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="multiple" default="false"/>
  <group if="$(arg multiple)" ns="$(arg robot)">
    <node pkg="turtlebot_dashboard" type="turtlebot_dashboard" name="turtlebot_dashboard"/>
  </group>
  <group if="$(arg multiple)">
    <node pkg="turtlebot_dashboard" type="turtlebot_dashboard" name="turtlebot_dashboard"/>
  </group>
</launch>
```

but I get this output:

roslaunch turtlebot_dashboard dasboard.launch 
... logging to /home/albert/.ros/log/9bcf1e54-435b-11e1-8782-ccaf78899509/roslaunch-albert-XPS-M1530-4631.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12700/launch-file-for-turtlebot-dashboard?/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your launch file, the two conditionals for launching inside a namespace or not are the same.  I think it should be:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="multiple" default="false"/>
  <group if="$(arg multiple)" ns="$(arg robot)">
    <node pkg="turtlebot_dashboard" type="turtlebot_dashboard" name="turtlebot_dashboard"/>
  </group>
  <group unless="$(arg multiple)">
    <node pkg="turtlebot_dashboard" type="turtlebot_dashboard" name="turtlebot_dashboard"/>
  </group>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2012-01-20**:
Yes, sorry, i've made a really stupid mistake copy-paste and not change! Thanks!